# Reflection Exception Property sava\UserBundle\Entity\User Tickets does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, schema, fosuserbundle

for some reason whenever i use `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` it gives me this error:

```
[ReflectionException]
Property sava\UserBundle\Entity\User::$Tickets does not exist
```

usually i first create the orm and then generate with doctrine:generate:entities, my problem is whenever im trying to update the schema, it gives me this error, i have already tried:

1. clear doctrine cache with php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query, clear mapping, ect.
2. manually deleting the cache folder.
3. deleting ticket entity and generating them again.
4. setting all the fields to protected.

i ran out of ideas.

error this are my dependencys.

User.Orm:

```
sava\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: User
    fields:
        id:
            id: true
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        nombreCliente:
            type: string
            length: 200
            fixed: false
            nullable: false
            column: nombre_cliente
        rifCedula:
            type: string
            length: 40
            fixed: false
            nullable: false
            column: rif_cedula
        telefono:
            type: string
            length: 30
            fixed: false
            nullable: true
        celular:
            type: string
            length: 30
            fixed: false
            nullable: true
        direccion:
            type: string
            length: 250
            fixed: false
            nullable: true
    oneToMany:
        Tickets:
            targetEntity: sava\SoporteBundle\Entity\TblTicket
            mappedBy: idUser
            cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Ticket.Orm.

```
sava\SoporteBundle\Entity\TblTicket:
    type: entity
    table: tbl_ticket
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        titulo:
            type: string
            length: '80'
        contenido:
            type: text
        isClosed:
            type: boolean
        fecha:
            type: date
    oneToMany:
        respuestas:
            targetEntity: sava\SoporteBundle\Entity\TblRespuesta
            mappedBy: ticket
            cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
    oneToOne:
        idUser:
            targetEntity: sava\UserBundle\Entity\User
            inversedBy: Tickets
            #nullable: true
            joinColumn:
                name: id_user
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Ticket entity(deleted some unrelated fields for clarity):

```
<?php

namespace sava\SoporteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TblTicket
 */
class TblTicket
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */

        public function __construct()
    {
        $this->respuestas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    protected $idUser;

        public function setIdUser(\sava\UserBundle\Entity\User $idUser = null)
    {
        $this->idUser = $idUser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idUser
     *
     * @return \sava\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getIdUser()
    {
        return $this->idUser;
    }
}
>
```

this is my ticket entity extended by fos/user/bundle (some fields where deleted for clarity):

```
namespace sava\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;


/**
 * user
 *
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->User = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    protected $Tickets;


    /**
     * Add Tickets
     *
     * @param \sava\SoporteBundle\Entity\TblTicket $tickets
     * @return User
     */
    public function addTicket(\sava\SoporteBundle\Entity\TblTicket $tickets)
    {
        $this->Tickets[] = $tickets;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove Tickets
     *
     * @param \sava\SoporteBundle\Entity\TblTicket $tickets
     */
    public function removeTicket(\sava\SoporteBundle\Entity\TblTicket $tickets)
    {
        $this->Tickets->removeElement($tickets);
    }

    /**
     * Get Tickets
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTickets()
    {
        return $this->Tickets;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind, an old bundle where i was testing the userbundle had an entity that somehow was being targeted by doctrine. deleted the old bundle and its working fine.

if you ever have this problem check your bundles for extra unwanted entities or the namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your entity first:

```
 php app/console doctrine:generate:entities [YourBundle:YouEntity]
```